# Is there any method to 'combine layers' in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

Let me explain my question:

I assume that there are some(more than one) tensorflow layers like below:

```
import tensorflow as tf
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[1,64,64,3])
conv_layer_1 = tf.layers.Conv2D(16,[3,3])
conv_layer_2 = tf.layers.Conv2D(16,[3,3])
```

Is there any method to combine these layers to one tf.Layer object?That means:

```
# conv_layer is the combined result    
# conv_layer(x) is equal to conv_layer2(conv_layer1(x))
conv_layer = some_function([conv_layer1,conv_layer2])
```

Currently I use a ugly method:

```
class MyLayer(tf.Layer)
    ......
    def combine(layers_list):
        self.layers_list += layers_list
    def __call__(x):
        for layer in self.layers:
            y = layer(y)
        return y
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use tf.layers.concatenate for this case
For more details visit tensorflow site https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/concatenate

Comment: tf.keras.layers.concatenate is similar with tf.layers.concat which is used for tensor instead of layer.